# python distribute dependency_links to local git repositories

Tags: python, git, dependencies, distribute

Lets say I have following 2 packages:

```
/srv/share/python/core
/srv/share/python/package1
```

which `package1` has dependency on `core` both have remote git repositories in:

```
/srv/git/core.git
/srv/git/package1.git
```

How do I define setup() in `package1`'s setup.py to install `core` from /srv/git/core.git automatically while installing `package1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally sorted it out, major problem was distribute was out of date as it couldn't recognise `git+file`
ran "`pip install -I distribute`" to update distribute to latest 0.6.35

then within setup()

```
 install_requires = ['core'],
 dependency_links = ['git+file:///srv/git/core.git/#egg=core'],
```